# How to open a HTML file from a link in another HTML file in android?

Tags: android, android-webview

All HTML files are stored in Android's asset folder.Whenever I click a link in my index.html the linked HTML page doesn't opens.

[image]

Here is the link which I am trying to open from index.html but its not working.

```
<a href="file:///android_asset/iv-therapy.html">IV Therapy</a>
```

Comment: Have you tried something like: `<a href="iv-therapy.html">IV Therapy</a>` ? Since those files are in the same directory so, you should be able to open it like that. Or : `/iv-therapy.html`

Comment: I have tried this approach already.Its not working.